# Increase the output a signal at different frequencies

Tags: c, audio, embedded, signal-processing, frequency

I'm writing a C program for a micro-controller. At the moment I've already written the functions that reads from an analog-to-digital converter port on the board, and a function that can create a delay (just a loop that takes time).

The incoming signal from a microphone is read into the board and each read value is stored in a table. The values stored in this table are intended to be output to a speaker at varying frequencies.

My question, given a table of values, how can you play/output the values at higher and lower frequencies.

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers on SO already about `pitch shifting` - try reading through some of these for ideas ?

Comment: Is this simply about how to replay the signal at more or less samples/second than it was originally acquired at?

Comment: Ideally your timing would be driven from a periodic timer interrupt rather than a delay loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want to resample your waveform samples before you play them at the same ADC/dAC rate, change the sample rate, or look into time-pitch modification, which is a much more complicated DSP process.

Comment: Thanks for a real answer. I already figured out earlier that you can, by altering the delay time between samples, change the pitch.